# Supress Guzzle User Deprecated Info

Tags: php, symfony, guzzle

I am writing some commands in Symfony 6.2 using Guzzle to talk to an API.

I have the following code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

class LocalApi extends Client
{
    public function getAssets(int $assetId)
    {
        $response = $this->request(
            'GET',
            "http://somedomain/{$assetId}",
            ['headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json']]
        );
        return json_decode($response->getBody(), 1);
    }
}
```

The code works fine and I get results, But underneath them I get the following warning (or info):

> 2023-05-02T14:11:57+00:00 [info] User Deprecated: The "GuzzleHttp\Client" class is considered final. It may change without further notice as of its next major version. You should not extend it from "App\Service\LocalApi".

How can I turn this off??

I'm using Symfony 6.2 and Guzzle 7.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like something that should be going to your logs, not into your output; maybe you have things configured in a "development mode" that outputs everything.

However, if you read the message, it's telling you that you shouldn't *extend* the `Client` class as you have here. Instead, *compose* your class to use a client as a *dependency*.

Most simply, you could create one directly:

```
class LocalApi
{
    public function getAssets(int $assetId) {
        $client = new Client;

        $response = $client->request(
            'GET',
            "http://somedomain/{$assetId}",
            ['headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json']]
        );
        return json_decode($response->getBody(), 1);
    }

}
```

But more flexibly, you should expect the code that creates the class to create a client first, and pass it in ("Dependency Injection"):

```
class LocalApi
{
    private Client $client;

    public function __construct(Client $client) {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function getAssets(int $assetId) {
        $response = $this->client->request(
            'GET',
            "http://somedomain/{$assetId}",
            ['headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json']]
        );
        return json_decode($response->getBody(), 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: I agree with everything, and since it was tagged as Symfony, the OP could use [`HttpClientInterface`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html) to get this

Comment: Thank you for the solutions, it makes a lot of sense but only the first one works.  I can't autowire it becuase i get the error message 'service not found'.

Comment: Actually the second one works, I just have to remove the arguments from the constructor but its essentially the same.  Thank you for your help, its a much more elegant solution.  The reason I extended it in the first place is because another project (using Guzzle 6) we have extended it, but I guess now in Guzzle 7 they've changed that.

Comment: @RichardBridge As the message says, they haven't changed it *yet*, but they *might do soon*.